# SQLite error when publishing .NET Core 2 Console App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm having issues publishing a .NET Core console app. It works fine when I run it from Visual Studio and I'm getting zero errors. However, when I publish it with:
dotnet publish -c release -r win-x64 --self-contained

I'm getting an error about SQLite. I'm using the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite library. The error I'm getting is:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>
> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I don't know what could be causing the issue and every single thing I find on the internet either doesn't work or doesn't apply to my situation. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've tried just about everything.

Comment: Which Sqlite library are you using?

Comment: maybe you don't have the sqlite 64bit installed?

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

This is the one I'm using, which works when I'm debugging, but it doesn't work after I publish.

Comment: @Aevan: Is there a `e_sqlite.dll` file in the same directory as your published application?

Comment: There wasn't. I found the .dll file and manually copied it to the output directory. It's working now! Any idea how to fix that issue in the future? Manually copying doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: Same problem when using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.2.3. Everything OK with 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite EF Core provider is technically a 3rd-party library, from the point of view of the .NET Core. You need to make sure that the dependencies are fixed up for your project, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli).

Basically, you need to make sure the dependency NuGet package is called out in your `.csproj` file as a dependency, like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="[version #]" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And you need to make sure the NuGet package is installed on your system, since the dependency is resolved from the *local* NuGet cache when the project is published.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `System.Data.SQLite` library then this exception is mentioned in their FAQ:

> https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q5
>
> **Why do I get a DllNotFoundException (for "sqlite3.dll" or "SQLite.Interop.dll") when trying to run my application?**
>
> Either the named dynamic link library (DLL) cannot be located or it cannot be loaded due to missing dependencies. Make sure the named dynamic link library is located in the application directory or a directory along the system PATH and try again. Also, be sure the necessary Visual C++ runtime redistributable has been installed unless you are using a dynamic link library that was built statically linked to it.

So:

1. Ensure you have the latest Visual C++ runtime installed: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019667
2. Ensure `sqlite3.dll` is in the same directory as the rest of your DLLs
3. Unrelated to your current issue, but ensure the build of your `sqlite3.dll` matches the ISA of your web-server process (i.e. ARM, x86, x64).
4. Ensure your web-application's host webserver process isn't being started with unusual environment variables, `PATH` or working-directory.

Comment: That's not the library I'm using. I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.